# How can I use a university-linked Outlook account on Mail for iPhone?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, office-365

My university has some sort of partnership with Microsoft so that we can use their Outlook interface to check our email. The email has the domain of our university and we login with our university login in order to access the service.

I’m able to add the account on the Outlook app for iPhone, but I would like to use it on the Mail app where I have all of my other accounts.

I’ve tried choosing the Outlook service when adding a new mail account, but it says the account doesn’t exist.

Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT: apparently the service is running on Office 365

Comment: I can't post this as an answer because I can't show the setup steps... Set it up as an "Other" type account, from Mail prefs [not from System Prefs/Internet Accounts - that hits a block you can't get round].
This forces everything you enter to be done manually, but means you can get the correct info in there. If you hit a point where it wants to 'check settings' let it try - it will fail. You can then continue again manually.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the Exchange service instead of Outlook. See Office support page [Set up email using the iOS Mail app](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Set-up-email-using-the-iOS-Mail-app-7e5b180f-bc8f-45cc-8da1-5cefc1e633d1#ID0EAACAAA=Office_365_work_or_school) under the ‘Office 365 work or school’ tab instead of ‘Outlook.com’.